# Binding CalendarDatePicker.Language property return Exception.HResult 0x800F0904

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I need to implement a variation of the same project for many different languages and I'm using the `CalendarDatePicker` object in some pages. I have to set its language depending on a property given by a `ini` file which is downloaded at the beginning of the launch.

I'm trying to bind its value like this:

```
<CalendarDatePicker x:Name="datePicker"                              
                    Language="{Binding LanguageINI}"/>
```

But I get this Exception: 0x800F0904.

I have also tried to set it up using code behind but, since the `CalendarDatePicker` it's entirely customised, I have to set also the Property in the `CalendarView` style so, I'm not succeeding at all and I don't know how to achieve it.

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Thx much!

Comment: Could you post the data context including the "LanguageINI" value?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue in my side. Using `Binding` with `Language` property will raise following error.

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800F0904

This error is given by XAML Designer. And if you debug with your code, you will get a more readable exception like following:
[image]

> An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in UWP.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> WinRT information: Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.Language'. [Line: 45 Position: 68]

You can try with [`{X:Bind}`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) to avoid this issue.

However, even you can set `Language` property, it also won't effect the language `CalendarDatePicker` used to shows. `CalendarDatePicker` has supported globalization and localization by default. It will automatically use system's default language to show its UI.

If you want to set your app's language depending on a property given by a ini file. You can use [ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.globalization.applicationlanguages.primarylanguageoverride.aspx) like:

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "zh-CN";
```

The `PrimaryLanguageOverride` is a simple override setting for apps that give users their own independent language choice. This will change the language your app used and `CalendarDatePicker` will automatically use this language to show.